# How to trigger Xdebug for HTTP requests not from a browser

Tags: php, xdebug

I have Xdebug configured and working as I want for standard requests from my browser.

I'm now trying to work with a third party API which makes requests to my script in response to external events (the API is a payment gateway which polls my script when a payment has succeeded). I can't control how the API requests my script, so I can't add the GET parameter `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=session_name` to trigger Xdebug. Is it possible to add something to my script or htaccess to make Xdebug triggered for all requests to my script? I think I can turn Xdebug on for all requests server wide, but I'd prefer not do do this as there are lots active scripts on my server and I don't want Xdebug triggered for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding URL parameter in the `.htaccess` as a rewrite rule?
For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^ip\.address\.of\.client$ # for more security.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/endpoint
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=session_name [QSA]
```

Flag [`QSA` (Apache Docs)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: I was considering this approach, but thought the debugger wouldn't trigger on the query string being added in htaccess. Turns out I was wrong, thank for the answer.